# Filtering Lookup Column By Expiration Date

Tags: 2013, javascript, custom-list, lookup-column, calculated-column

Scenario: I have created a lookup column  with two columns.  A department column and Expiration Date column.  Each Department has a Expiration Date.  For example see the image.  When the Department Expiration date is met or passed, I want the department to drop off the lookup column list.

[image]

Possible Solution:
  1. Create the look up column and enter in the department names and expiration dates

I created a calculated column that filters the lookup column and the dates.  (I think)

This is the formula I used:

```
=DATEIF([DepartmentExpDate]=>TODAY,"")
```

The formula is not working.  I am not sure if any of this is correct.

Question:  How would I filter the lookup column to have the department drop off the list once the Expiration date equals today's date or passes automatically?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Thank you!  This option you have to add another column (deactivate) the department.  I do not believe the question addresses if you are using dates as the way of removing the department.  Am I correct?

Comment: Try the answer in the other question.  If it doesn't work, you can edit your question with that detail, which would be enough to remove the duplicate question flag.